# Get previous version code of app when installing new version programatically in android?

Tags: android

I want to get the previous version code of an application when new version of the application is being installed.

**What i tryied:**

I have implemented following class and it will get run when new version is being installed.
But i can only get the new version code.

```
 public class VersionContraller extends BroadcastReceiver {  

    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

       if(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(intent.getAction()))  { 

           if(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart().equals(context.getPackageName())) { 


            try {
                 PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
                 int newVersion=pInfo.versionCode;   
                //I want to do some logic hear with older and new version of the application
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           }
       }
    }
}
```

**How can i get the previous version of the application inside above class?**

Comment: You'll probably have to keep track of the current installed version manually. Since the boradcast is only taking place after the package is already replaced, the packagemanager will not have the old version information anymore.

Comment: @kaluwila did you solved your problem? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't do this very easely. You can use SharedPreferences in your code, like this:

```
String newVersion;
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    int intVersion = pInfo.versionCode;
    newVersion = "" + intVersion;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // Put a version you want if exception is launched
    newVersion = "something you want";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("your.package.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedVersion = "your.package.app.savedVersion";
String versionOnSP = sharedPrefs.getString(savedVersion, "previous");
if (versionOnSP.equalsIgnoreCase("previous") && newVersion.equalsIgnoreCase("versionTarget")) {
    // Your version is old; do some logic here with older version of the application
    ...
} else {
    // Your version is new, do whatever you want
}
// After that, save your current version
sharedPrefs.edit().putString(savedVersion, newVersion).commit();
```

In this way, at the first launch after update you will be able to do some operation because you haven't save a *version* on SharedPreferences in previous release.

But **it is not 100% safe**, because user can delete data of your app, and after a re-launch of the app you will go directly on first if. Maybe my idea need an improvement.

EDIT (after bgse comments)

My code must be placed into the first if:

```
public class VersionContraller extends BroadcastReceiver {  
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        if(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(intent.getAction()))  {
            // My code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, you could listen for PACKAGE_INSTALLED and PACKAGE_REPLACED. Do a double-check to see if you do have some old version information even if the broadcast says its a fresh install, in case the user did uninstall before.

Comment: @bgse are you suggesting to replace SharedPreferences with PACKAGE_REPLACED in if condition?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that was a bit unclear. I suggested listening for both broadcasts (as both, even PACKAGE_INSTALLED, can hint to an upgrade in case the user did uninstall at some point), and apply your suggestion. I was under the impression the OP was after a version history for 3rd party apps. In case of a previous version check for your own package, your approach is perfectly fine, in fact you'd lose your history anyway once the sharedprefs are cleared on uninstall.